# XPath Oracle SQL Select Element

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I have an XML document that is structured like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Agregat xmlns:DGE="urn:ops:rncps:dge" xmlns:SNGI="urn:cnav:sngi">
<DGE:Entete PGMD_Profil="SORTIEDGE" Profil_Version="01.02">
<DGE:Identification>195a3415-94de-45d3-a4a4-144055c7e2bb</DGE:Identification>
<DGE:Temps>2016-06-02T14:49:31.401+02:00</DGE:Temps>
<DGE:RefService>M0004E001</DGE:RefService>
<DGE:VersionService>01.01</DGE:VersionService>
<DGE:NbDoc>23</DGE:NbDoc>
<DGE:Emetteur>
  <DGE:Identite R="RFO">99640000</DGE:Identite>
  <DGE:Qualite>OPDGE</DGE:Qualite>
</DGE:Emetteur>
<DGE:Recepteur>
  <DGE:Identite R="RFO">00171002</DGE:Identite>
  <DGE:Qualite>CONSDGE</DGE:Qualite>
</DGE:Recepteur>
</DGE:Entete>
</Agregat>
```

I would like to select the value of the element "DGE:NbDoc" which is 23.

The SQL query that I produced is:

```
SELECT RPAD(extractValue(Entete.column_value, '//NbDoc'),2,' ') AS NbDoc
FROM COMMUN.SESSION_TEMP_XML s
,TABLE( XMLSequence( extract( s.xml_data 
,'//Agregat//Entete','xmlns:DGE="urn:ops:rncps:dge"') ) ) Entete
```

How can I select the value of NbDoc Element?

Comment: `//*[local-name()='Agregat']/DGE:NbDoc/.` Not sure if it will work in oracle xpath, you can try.

Comment: This Xpath doesn't compile.

Comment: please show the error that you were getting before

Comment: Thats the problem, i'm gettin empty result, no error. thx svasa for investigating!

Comment: sorry my previous xpath was missing entete, try : `//*[local-name()='Agregat']/DGE:Entete/DGE:NbDoc/text()`

Comment: Svasa, you're right, this work on XML simulator http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html, but it doesn't work on Oracle, wich is the subjet of my question !

Comment: You need to declare the XML namespace like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439595/how-to-query-xml-with-namespaces-in-oracle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query XML with namespaces in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439595/how-to-query-xml-with-namespaces-in-oracle)