# What is the correct way to extract de value from this XML in Oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

Im trying to extract de text value from a XML node in Oracle. Im not really sure how to do it and I don´t fully understand the Oracle documentation since it seem to be many ways to do it.
How would you extract de node "ErrorMessage" from this node?

Thanks

```html
'<soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
          <faultstring>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <Error xmlns="SSoapException">
                <ErrorNumber>REF17</ErrorNumber>
                <ErrorMessage>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</ErrorMessage>
              </Error>
           </detail>
    </soap:Fault>'
```

I expect to extract the "ErrorMessage" node using a select.

I was trying this but does not work

```html
SELECT
 xmltype('
 <soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
          <faultstring>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <Error xmlns="SSoapException">
                <ErrorNumber>REF17</ErrorNumber>
                <ErrorMessage>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</ErrorMessage>
              </Error>
           </detail>
    </soap:Fault>').extract('soap:Fault"/faultstring/text()').getstringval()
 FROM dual
```

Comment: Divide and conquer: are you able to extract the string code? Then, does the SQL query (alone) work?

Comment: The problem seems to be <Error xmlns="SSoapException"> if I remove de xmlns i works...

Comment: The problem is that you are not declaring the namespace nor ussing it in the xPath expression. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439595/how-to-query-xml-with-namespaces-in-oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query XML with namespaces in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439595/how-to-query-xml-with-namespaces-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with the tag "soap:Fault".. system was not able to recognize the tag.

Because with this particular code you can get the result..

```
SELECT xmltype('
<soap xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
          <faultstring>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <Error xmlns="SSoapException">
                <ErrorNumber>REF17</ErrorNumber>
                <ErrorMessage>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</ErrorMessage>
              </Error>
           </detail>
    </soap>
    ').extract('soap/faultstring/text()').getstringval()
  FROM dual;
```

result is

```
No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.
```

So, as work around you can user the below code...

```
SELECT xmltype(replace('
<soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
          <faultstring>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <Error xmlns="SSoapException">
                <ErrorNumber>REF17</ErrorNumber>
                <ErrorMessage>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</ErrorMessage>
              </Error>
           </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
    ','soap:Fault','new_tag')).extract('new_tag/faultstring/text()').getstringval()
  FROM dual;
```

and the result is

```
No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.
```

Here I am replacing the tag 'soap:Fault' with some new tag and then extracting the value..

This might not be the perfect approach.. but it will works.. ;)

Comment: Thanks but that works if you try to get faultstring but I can't make it work with "ErrorMessage" sub node (inside detail)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  xmltype('
  <soap:Fault xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
          <faultstring>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <Error xmlns="SSoapException">
                <ErrorNumber>REF17</ErrorNumber>
                <ErrorMessage>No existe la referencia del codigo de Hospital Publico.</ErrorMessage>
              </Error>
           </detail>
    </soap:Fault>').extract('//*:Fault/faultstring/text()').getstringval()
  FROM dual
```